# error 100 parse restful api with ionic

Tags: rest, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am fairly new to angular and new to ionic. I created an app with parse rest api. Everything works fine when I developed the app, I could log in and retrieve all the information I needed from the data bases but when I compiled and installed the app on my tablet I got a 100 error while logging in. Has any one else encountered this error?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you're suffering from Cordova Whitelist problem.

Cordova 4.0 brought a new way of whitelisting external resources. To be able to use it now add this Cordova plugin to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

You may (not necessary) also add this line to your index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Be warned, these settings are excellent for a development environment, use more conservative values for your production environment.

Read more about this plugin and Ionic-Framework here: http://www.gajotres.net/whitelist-external-resources-and-api-calls-ionic-framework/

**EDIT:**

Try another one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the case. I tried to add the plugin and add the meta data. I still get error 100 while trying to login or retrieve information from parse rest api.

Comment: Please try this other example, apparently original one will not work with some services, including Google Maps. Also have you tried debugging your app (on your tablet) using Google Chrome Remote Debugging (for Android tablets) or Safari Remote Debugging (for iPad)?